# Prevent output of SPOOL from being wrapped

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, spool

I'm trying to generate all DDLs for objects in a Database using the SPOOL command in SQLPLUS:

```
SET trimspool ON
SET wrap off
SET heading off
SET linesize 300
SET echo off
SET pages 999
SET long 90000
Col object_type format a10000
Col object_name format a10000
Col owner format a10000

spool export.out

SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL(object_type, object_name, owner)
FROM all_OBJECTS 
WHERE OWNER = 'DMALM' 
and object_type not like '%PARTITION'
and object_type not like '%BODY'
and object_type not like '%LOB';

spool off
quit
```

But the output file I get is cut at col #80.
How can I prevent the output file from being wrapped?

Comment: Are you sure the data in the file is wrapped, rather than your text editor wrapping it?

Comment: @AlexPoole I'm using notepad++ to open the file and the wrap option is turned off..

Comment: You are keeping the linesize to 300 bytes but keeping length of object_type,object_name,owner to ten thousand (i.e a10000). make them to a30 as none of them can be larger than that... plus you need to use DBMS_METADATA.SET_TRANSFORM_PARAM to set the various parameters so that your output is as per required format.

Comment: Those `col` settings are irrelevant as those columns aren't included in the result set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using word_wrapped?

```
SET trimspool ON
SET heading off
SET linesize 300
SET echo off
SET pages 999
SET long 90000
set termout off
column txt format a121 word_wrapped
Col object_type format a10000
Col object_name format a10000
Col owner format a10000
spool export.out

SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL(object_type, object_name, owner)txt
FROM all_OBJECTS 
WHERE OWNER = 'DMALM' 
and object_type not like '%PARTITION'
and object_type not like '%BODY'
and object_type not like '%LOB';

spool off
quit
```

Comment: That works but loses the indentation applied by default (with 'pretty'  turned on in the DBMS_METADATA transformation parameters).

Answer (score 7):

You need to also do:

```
SET longchunksize 90000
```

As [the documentation says](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_six.htm#sthref572):

> The default width of datatype columns is the width of the column in the database. The column width of a `LONG`, `BLOB`, `BFILE`, `CLOB`, `NCLOB` or `XMLType` defaults to the value of `SET LONGCHUNKSIZE` or `SET LONG`, whichever is the smaller.

You're setting `LONG` already, but `LONGCHUNKSIZE` is still at its default value of 80, so you need to increase that to match. You can see all your current settings with `show all`.

This preserves the line breaks and indentation [applied by default](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_metada.htm#ARPLS66910).

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you may want to try:

```
set longchunksize 100
```

or equivalent. Experiment with the number see if it helps.

Source [Oracle Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve040.htm#i2699146)

Answer (score -1):

The following works. You can download all SPs under one schema. You can also download one SP at a time.

```
CREATE or replace DIRECTORY DIR_DDL AS '/dir_name';
grant read, write on directory DIR_DDL to user_name;


-- ====================================================
-- NOTE:  Need to use the object owner user, not SYS.
-- ====================================================

DECLARE
  v_ddl_clob  CLOB;

BEGIN

  FOR c IN ( SELECT object_name, object_type
               FROM dba_objects
              WHERE object_type IN ('PROCEDURE')
                AND OWNER = 'SYS'
                AND object_name = 'SP_NAME' )
  LOOP
--  You want "/" in a new line.  Otherwise, it will not work
    v_ddl_clob := dbms_metadata.get_ddl(c.object_type, c.object_name) ||'
    /';

    -- write to SQL directory :
    dbms_xslprocessor.clob2file(v_ddl_clob, 'DIR_DDL', c.object_name||'.sql');

  END LOOP;

END;
/
```

Comment: The OP specifically asked about spool, which writes to files on the client machine. This will write to files on the server. Useful of course, but not a correct/relevant answer to this specific question.